# How to create structures in python like we can in Visual Basic?

Tags: python, vb.net, data-structures, structure

For example we can create a structure:

```
Structure Student
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim name As String
    Dim DoB As Date
End Structure
```

And later we can declare variables in this structure as if it was a datatype and input values for the fields.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a(4) As Student
    For i = 1 to 5
    Console.Write("Enter name of student no." & i & ": ")
    a(i).name = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Enter id of student no." & i & ": ")
    a(i).id = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Enter Date of Birth of student no." & i & ": ")
    a(i).DoB = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine("Student ID    Student Name    Student Date of Birth")
    For i = 1 to 5 
    Console.WriteLine(a(i).ID & "            " & a.(i).Name & "     " & a(i).DoB)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub()
```

How can we do something similar in python?

Comment: Yes you would use a class. Python is a class-based, object-oriented language

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes

```py
class student():
    def __init__(self,id,name,dob):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob

    def __str__(self):
        return """
        id: {0} 
        name: {1} 
        dob: {2}
        """.format(self.id,self.name,self.dob)


import datetime
dob = datetime.datetime(1997, 1, 18)

can = student(150,"can",dob)

print(can)
```

[python classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3's [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) is a less verbose version of a standard python class which just like a normal Python class can have functions in it.

```
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Student:
    id: int = 0 # '= 0' implies default value, if not supplied with 's'
    name: str
    dob: datetime.datetime

s = Student(id=1, name="A name" dob=datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 6))
print(s) # Student(id=1, name='A name', dob=datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 6, 0,0))
```